求人兼SNSアプリの開発について
概要
簡易宿泊施設（ゲストハウスやホステル）が募集する求人（フリーアコモデーション）をマッチングさせて、かつ利用者が宿泊施設での経験や評価などをタイムリーに共有できるSNSのようなアプリを作って運営してみたいと考えています。最初は日本で。結果的にあわよくば世界へ向けて。
質問
上記のようなアプリやサイトを作成、運営する場合に適した
・開発言語
・必要な開発人員数
・開発人員の役割分担
・開発期間
・開発費
・運営に必要な人員や費用
など予想される限り（上記以外の条件を答えていただけても喜びます）の情報を教えていただきたいです。
補足
質問主はITに関して全くの素人であり興味本位での質問であるため、正解である必要もなく、回答者様の自由に回答くださいませ。回答いただけただけで喜びます♪

「教えてほしい情報」が多すぎます。箇条書きした項目を一つに絞ってください。

「アプリを作って運営」したいのか「興味本位での質問」なのかどっちでしょうか？前者の場合用意できる資本と期間はどのくらいなのでしょうか？

聞きたいことが多すぎるため、「開発言語」だけ回答します。
とりあえず、できるだけ早くサービスを立ち上げたいのであれば、Ruby on Rails(以下、Rails)一択です。かのTwitterも最初の実装はRailsでしたし、他の多くのサービスでもRailsが選択されています。
Rubyは遅いとか、大規模向きじゃ無いとか、色々言われますが、まず、そのサービスがどれだけ広まるかわからないのに、速度や処理能力の改善に労力を掛ける意味はありません。サービスが浸透し、グレードアップが必要になったとき、例えどんな言語で作った物でも、一から作り直しになります。その時に、資金が十分貯まっていれば、どんな言語でも選択し放題です。
では、なぜ、Railsがいいのかというと、開発速度が尋常じゃ無く速いからです。その一点です。なお、スマホで動くネイティブアプリでなくてもまずはWebで十分です。APIをきちんと用意していれば、ネイティブアプリは後から追加で作れます。(Twitterも最初は公式のネイティブアプリはなく、サードパーティー製のアプリだけでした。)
ということで、私だったら、Railsを選択します。

ぶっちゃけ、どんな言語でもチューリング完全であれば、質問で言っているサービスは作れます。あとはWebアプリケーションのフレームワークがあった方が作りやすいと言った程度です。そして、主要な言語のほとんどにWebアプリケーションのフレームワークがあります。個人がどれを選ぶかは、好みの問題です。では、企業がどれを選ぶかについては、下記のようなことを材料に総合的に判断します。

開発期間
資金
開発に用意できる人員(その人達が一体何が書けるか)
現在の資産(流用可能な既存のコード)
予測される規模(同時接続数やユーザー数・データ量等)
求められる応答速度
提供される形態(Webだけでいい？iOSやAndroidアプリも同時リリースが必須？)

よほど特殊な物でない限り、作る物の内容はあまり関係ありません。ここまで来ると経営戦略の話です。技術的な情報はただの材料であって、技術者にとってはなんの面白みもない、利益を最大にするにはどうすればいいのかという議論だけで決まります。
